# Converting bitmap to Opencv::Mat in JNI

Tags: android, c++, opencv, bitmap, java-native-interface

I am building a image processing project in Android. I capture bitmap pictures through camera, and feed it to the opencv C++ function through JNI.

Firstly, I test my opencv c++ function using saved bitmap pictures (PNG format), and it it successful.

```
  // in Android, save bitmap
  Bitmap bmp = YUV_420_888_toRGB(img,img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());
  try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    Log.e(TAG,"saved successfully.)");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }

  // in opencv c++ function
  Mat im = imread("/Users/Jun/Downloads/20170227/P9/1488167433596_frame.PNG");

  // processing im
```

Then i feed each captured bitmap picture to the same opencv c++ function. However, the detected result is totally different. I think there must be some errors when converting bitmap in Java to opencv mat in C++ through JNI. Please find the converting codes below:

```
   //Java side:
   public static int[] detector(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    int []pixels = new int[w*h];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels,0,w,0,0,w,h);

   return detect(pixels,w,h);

}

private static native int[] detect(int pixels[],int w,int h);


  // c++ side:
  JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL     Java_com_example_jun_helloworld_JNIUtils_detect(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jintArray buf, jint w, jint h) {
jint* cbuf = env->GetIntArrayElements(buf, false);
if (cbuf == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
Mat im(h, w, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *) cbuf);

// processing im
```

The two "im"s should be different. Can someone tell me what's wrong in the converting? thanks.

Comment: Note that jint is 32 bits long while char is just 16.

Comment: So you mean the "CV_8UC4" is incorrect?

Comment: Nope, this one: (unsigned char *) cbuf

Comment: What should i change  it to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you cast int pointer to char pointer. So, you will change the way your code treats your data.

Take a look here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    // what you have in the code is array of ints
    int iarray[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *iarray_ptr = iarray;

    // and you cast int pointer to char pointer
    char *carray_ptr = (char *) iarray_ptr;

    // so, you simply skip some values because of
    // pointer aritmetics; your data are shifted
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("int: %p, char %p\n", iarray_ptr + i, carray_ptr + i);
    }

    // you can always do something like this
    char carray2[5];
    for(int p=0;p<5;p++) {
        // you can loose precision here!
        carray2[p] = (char) iarray[p];
    }

    // and then, you can simply pass &carray2 to
    // to your code
}
```

If you run the code, you can clearly see what will be the difference in pointer arithmetics:

```
./pointer
int: 0x7fff51d859f0, char 0x7fff51d859f0
int: 0x7fff51d859f4, char 0x7fff51d859f1
int: 0x7fff51d859f8, char 0x7fff51d859f2
int: 0x7fff51d859fc, char 0x7fff51d859f3
int: 0x7fff51d85a00, char 0x7fff51d859f4
```

After casting to char *, you will simply "scatter" your data.